# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 my API deployed works but after amount of time it stop responding

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

so i have an issue on deploying my work n WSO2 **EI 6.6.0** the probleme is when i deploy my api it works at first time but after minutes it stop working and while i try send a get request using postman it shows me could not get response.

Comment: Do you observe any errors or warns in the carbon log

Comment: nothing appear on logs , but we managed it we used micro-integrator (entreprise integrator 7.1.0)